# Void is an invalid type for the variable highlightt

Tags: java, public, void

So i've got another horrible error on Java. I've got this code:

```
class MyHighlightPainter extends DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter {
    public MyHighlightPainter(Color color) {
        super(color);
    }   

Highlighter.HighlightPainter myHighlightPainter = new MyHighlightPainter(Color.yellow);

public void highlightt(JTextArea textComp, String pattern) {
    try {
        Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
        Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
        String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
        int pos = 0;

        while((pos=text.toUpperCase().indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase(),pos))>=0) {

            hilite.addHighlight(pos, pos+pattern.length(), myHighlightPainter);
            pos +=pattern.length();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

} 

search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            highlightt(field, word.getText());
        }
    });
```

And On `highlightt(field, word.getText());` error that undefined for the type new ActionListener

Can anyone help me? Thanks :).

Comment: I suspect it is a problem with a previous line, like an unclosed comment or something. Please post more code from earlier in the file.

Comment: you are not declaring things inside class.

Comment: Move the method highlightt() inside the class definition of MyHighlightPainter.

Comment: `UPDATED WITH EARLIER CODE` ?? it would be better if you link your question clearly rather than hoping the people will browse and link your old question.

Comment: @user2056954 I had to rollback your last edit. Please don't delete your question, as this might be of interest to future visitors. If you want to let us know the solution that you finally followed, post it as an answer to your own question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the method definition and instance declaration inside class -

do this

```
 class MyHighlightPainter extends DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter {
        public MyHighlightPainter(Color color) {
            super(color);
        }   

    Highlighter.HighlightPainter myHighlightPainter = new MyHighlightPainter(Color.yellow);

    public void highlightt(JTextArea textComp, String pattern) {
        try {
            Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
            Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
            String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
            int pos = 0;

            while((pos=text.toUpperCase().indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase(),pos))>=0) {

                hilite.addHighlight(pos, pos+pattern.length(), myHighlightPainter);
                pos +=pattern.length();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

} // close class
```

Comment: But then error on:
search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    highlightt(field, word.getText());
   }
  });

Comment: @user2056954 honestly I don't see any such code in your question

Comment: @user2056954 where is the declaration of `search` variable ?

Comment: `search = new JButton ("Search");` You mean this?

Comment: just move that part also inside class

Comment: Then on: `search.addActionListener` Error: Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead. And on: `});` Error: Mutliple markers on this line. :/